# Can I handle HTML5 events with C# handlers?

Tags: c#, html, handler

I have a button

```
     <input type="submit" value="Click Me" onclick="substitute()"/>
```

In one of my first HTML5 pages. Is there anyway I can write the body of the substitute method in C# code?

Or is it that I have no other option other than JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to have C# respond to a web page is to POST the page to a web server, or execute an AJAX request.  On the web server side, your request will execute some method that contains C# code.

But it really depends on what you are trying to do; some things are better handled in the browser.  Study up on ASP.NET MVC and Javascript, and your strategy will become clearer.

Comment: Thanks, so I have to use Javascript because my browser cannot parse C# but I can use the Javascript to call a service which is written in C#, right?

Answer (score 0):

Like an alternative, I can offer you to look on

[TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Samples/) which is JavaScript language's superscript, with the syntax comfortable for `C#` developers made by `Microsoft`.

*Very* interesting and promising project, but still in active development, as far as I know, so keep an I on regressions and retrocompatibility, if you decide to you use it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools that you can use to write code in C# that will be run in the browser. However this requires automatic translation of C# into JavaScript (as only JS is supported by all browsers). This maybe useful if you want to share code in C# between your Desktop app and Web app. The drawback is that any error on the page will be in the auto-generated JavaScript and you will have to somehow map this to your C# code, which may be hard.

Take a look on:

- [JSIL](http://jsil.org/try/)
- [Saltarelle](http://www.saltarelle-compiler.com/)

You can find more information in the Miguel de Icaza blog post:
http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Sep-06.html